# How to do ssh jump over two jump hosts in command line

Tags: ssh

I can't get connection chain with ssh one liner to work.

Chain: 
My PC -> jumphost -> Bastion  -> my app X host(sharing subnet with Bastion)

-Jumphost expect private key A

-Bastion and X host both expect private key B

```
my pc> ssh -i /path_to_priv_key_for_X/id_rsa -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o 
"ProxyCommand ssh -p 22 -W %h:%p -o \"ProxyCommand ssh -p 24 -W %h:%p 
-i /path_to_key_jump/id_rsa jumphostuser@jumphostdomain\"     -i 
/path_to_bastion_key/id_rsa bastionuser@ip_to_bastion" myappuser@subnet_ip
```

Above does not work, but

```
ssh -i  /path_to_bastion_key/id_rsa -o "ProxyCommand ssh -p 24 -W 
%h:%p -i /path_to_key_jump/id_rsa jumphostuser@jumphostdomain" 
bastionuser@ip_to_bastion
```

works, so I can access bastion with one liner, but adding app x host in the command chain does not work, wonder why?

I can step by step manually access the myapp X host like this

```
mypc> ssh -p 24 -i path_to_key_jump/id_rsa jumphostuser@jumphostdomain
jumphost> ssh -i /path_to_bastion_key/id_rsa bastionuser@ip_to_bastion
bastion> ssh myappuser@subnet_ip
myapp>
```

How to make in command line two hops over two jump hosts both requiring different key without ssh config?

Comment: Can you copy the private key to your PC? Then, something like `-o ProxyJump=jumphostuser@jumphostdomain,bastionuser@ip_to_bastion` might work, if you set up `ssh-agent` on your PC and enable agent forwarding as well.

Answer (score 2):

Something which is working for me surprisingly well is ssh with `-J` option:

> ```
>  -J destination
>          Connect to the target host by first making a ssh connection
> to the jump host described by destination and then establishing a TCP
> forwarding to the ultimate destination from there.
> ```

In fact, I's about its feature which I was not aware of for very long time:

> ```
> Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters.
> ```

So multi-hop like `PC -> jump server 1 -> jump server 2 -> target server` (in my example: `PC -> vpn -> vnc -> ece server` can be done with one combo:

```
$ ssh -J vpn,scs694@tr200vnc rms@tr001tbece11
```

Of course, most handy is to have ssh keys to open pwd-less connections (`PC->vpn` and `vpn -> vnc` and `vnc -> target`.

I hope it will help,
Jarek

Answer (score 2):

To add to the above. My use-case was a triple-hop to a database server, which looked like Server 1 (Basic Auth) --> Server 2 (Token) --> Server 3 (Basic Auth) --> DB Server (Port Forward).

After quite a few hours of turmoil, the solution was:

```
ssh -v -4 -J username@server1,username@server2 -N username@Server3 -L 1122:dbserver:{the_database_port_number}
```

Then I was able to just have the DB client hit localhost:1122 where 1122 can be any free port number on your localhost.

Comment: Excellent, would be good to understand `-4` and `-v` and `-N`, it is not so complexed.

Comment: @KangqiaoZhao IPv4, verbose detail, No remote command execution